# Hide/Show using class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do here is to hide/show divs based on the value selected from a dropdown.

Here's the thing.

Dropdown lists a set of class rooms.

There is a parent div named `listUserGrid` which has child divs. Each child div represents a student. So, when a particular class is selected, I am trying to show only those students who belong to it.

Relation between a student and a class is through the name of the class which is specified as a class element.
So, students belonging to class 2019 will have a class property named `c209` and so on.

I'm able to fetch the class but hiding ain't working.

```
<section class="content">

  <select id="class" name="class" data-placeholder="Select A Class">
    <option value="">-- All Class --</option>
    <option value="209">Class 209</option>
    <option value="210">Class 210</option>
    <option value="211">Class 211</option>
    <option value="212">Class 212</option>
    <option value="213">Class 213</option>
    <option value="214">Class 214</option>
  </select>

  <div id="listUserGrid" class="row">
    <div class="c209">user a</div>
    <div class="c210">user b</div>
    <div class="c211">user c</div>
    <div class="c212">user d</div>
    <div class="c213">user e</div>
    <div class="c214">user f</div>
    <div class="c209">user g</div>
    <div class="c210">user h</div>
    <div class="c211">user i</div>
    <div class="c212">user j</div>
    <div class="c213">user k</div>
    <div class="c214">user l</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#class').on('change', function() {
    var selected = this.value;
    if (selected) {
      var selClass = 'c' + selected;
      console.log(selClass);
      $('#listUserGrid :not(.selClass)').addClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('#listUserGrid').children().show();
    }

  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e06p8L0d/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#class').on('change', function() {
    var selected = this.value;
    if (selected) {
      var selClass = 'c' + selected;
      console.log(selClass);
      $('#listUserGrid :not(.'+selClass+')').addClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('#listUserGrid').children().show();
    }

  });
})
```

```css
.hide{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content">

  <select id="class" name="class" data-placeholder="Select A Class">
    <option value="">-- All Class --</option>
    <option value="209">Class 209</option>
    <option value="210">Class 210</option>
    <option value="211">Class 211</option>
    <option value="212">Class 212</option>
    <option value="213">Class 213</option>
    <option value="214">Class 214</option>
  </select>

  <div id="listUserGrid" class="row">
    <div class="c209">user a</div>
    <div class="c210">user b</div>
    <div class="c211">user c</div>
    <div class="c212">user d</div>
    <div class="c213">user e</div>
    <div class="c214">user f</div>
    <div class="c209">user g</div>
    <div class="c210">user h</div>
    <div class="c211">user i</div>
    <div class="c212">user j</div>
    <div class="c213">user k</div>
    <div class="c214">user l</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Concat your selector properly

Comment: before hiding the children, we'll have to `show()` them first. Nothing is displayed on selecting an option 2nd time. A small change is still required here.

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e06p8L0d/1/)**.

**Problems :**

1. When you add class `hide` then perform the `.show()` it will not remove the class so the element will not shown.
2. `selClass` is a variable so you can't just call it as string in `:not(.selClass)` but you've to concatenate the variable with selector like `$('#listUserGrid :not(.'+selClass+')')`.
3. You should shows the other students before hidding those who not match.

**Suggested solution :**

Use `show/hide` instead of using class `hide` :

```
if (selected) {
  var selClass = 'c' + selected;

  $('#listUserGrid div').show();
  $('#listUserGrid :not(.'+selClass+')').hide();
} else {
  $('#listUserGrid div').show();
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#class').on('change', function() {
    var selected = this.value;

    if (selected) {
      var selClass = 'c' + selected;

      $('#listUserGrid div').show();
      $('#listUserGrid :not(.'+selClass+')').hide();
    } else {
      $('#listUserGrid div').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content">

  <select id="class" class="" name="class" data-placeholder="-- Select A Class* --">
    <option value="">-- All Class --</option>
    <option value="209">Class 209</option>
    <option value="210">Class 210</option>
    <option value="211">Class 211</option>
    <option value="212">Class 212</option>
    <option value="213">Class 213</option>
    <option value="214">Class 214</option>
  </select>

  <div id="listUserGrid" class="row">
    <div class="c209">user a</div>
    <div class="c210">user b</div>
    <div class="c211">user c</div>
    <div class="c212">user d</div>
    <div class="c213">user e</div>
    <div class="c214">user f</div>
    <div class="c209">user g</div>
    <div class="c210">user h</div>
    <div class="c211">user i</div>
    <div class="c212">user j</div>
    <div class="c213">user k</div>
    <div class="c214">user l</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector is incorrectly called.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#class').on('change', function() {
    // Display all the children before hiding them
    $('#listUserGrid').children().show();
    var selected = this.value;
    if (selected) {
      var selClass = 'c' + selected;
      console.log(selClass);
      $('#listUserGrid :not(.' + selClass + ')').hide();
    }
  });
});
```